# Having specific htaccess credentials for one URL different from rest of site

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup a site so that I a username and password is needed to access the site in general, but for a specific location a different username and password is needed, with the more general username and password not working for that location.

This is from my httpd.conf at present:

```
<Location "/store/dashboard">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please Enter Password"
    AuthUserFile /home/user/webapps/blue_webapp/.htpasswd
    Require user blueadmin
</Location>

<Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please Enter Password"
    AuthUserFile /home/user/webapps/blue_webapp/.htpasswd
    Require user blue
</Location>
```

The problem is the second location block seems to override the first. When I change the second location block to require valid-user I can login to the /store/dashboard location with blueadmin, but this also means blueadmin can be used to login to the rest of the site which is not what I want.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I must send an answer.

The problem is (as far as I know): You wan't to access `/store/dashboard`
but you need also the right to see `/` because `/store/dashboard` is a subdirectory of `/`.

You can use a subdomain:

`/` => `example.com`

`/store/dashboard` => `dashboard.example.com`

Then you can/must use 2 vhosts with own `/` directory.

But I am not sure.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your answer. I don't want to have to setup subdomains though if it can be avoided.

Comment: This link guids you through vhosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: I don't think vhosts are the answer here, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is the second location block seems to override the first.

Yes.

I feel I must be missing something here, but you simply need to reverse your two `<Location>` blocks:

```
<Location "/">
  :
  Require user blue
</Location>

<Location "/store/dashboard">
  :
  Require user blueadmin
</Location>
```

Now, user `blue` can access the entire site, except for `/store/dashboard`. And `blueadmin` can only access `/store/dashboard` and not the rest of the site. In other words, "the second location block overrides the first". Which seems to be what you require?

However, a potential problem with this scenario is that `blueadmin` cannot access any (possibly *shared*) resources outside of the `/store/dashboard` URL tree. But I assume this is not an issue in your scenario?

Comment: That did appear to fix it, although it kept trying to load assets from outside of /store/dashboard which needed the sitewide creds, which is annoying. To fix this I would have to have a location block for each location I guess, which is frustrating.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, if pages inside `/store/dashboard` reference resources elsewhere on the site then authorization will naturally fail for this user. Ordinarily, you would expect an "admin" to have access to _everything_, so `blueadmin` would have access to `<Location "/">` as well - although that does not appear to be desirable for you. Alternatively, create a separate auth-block just for the _shared resources_. Or make sure `/store/dashboard` is self-contained and has no external dependencies.

Comment: You may also be able to "poke holes" through the authorization just for static assets, `.css`, `.js`, images, etc. ?

Comment: What do you mean by poke holes?

Comment: "poke holes" - Have _exceptions_ (holes) for specific URL-paths (perhaps denoted by a _pattern_) that does not require HTTP Authentication - overriding a preceding section that blocks _everything_. In a similar way as you are already doing above.